# Is it possible to install Cobos in Eclipse Indigo, running on Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide, cobol

I have Ubuntu 12 installed on my laptop and I want to have an IDE that allows me to develop both in Java and COBOL. The only version of eclipse available in the Ubuntu Software Center is Indigo. 
The problem is that, until now, what I read about COBOS, the open source COBOL IDE perfect for the job, is supposed to run only in Eclipse Helios, and Windows. 
My question is if anyone has come across this problem and how did you solve it. Is there anyway I could install COBOS in Eclipse? 
I've downloaded COBOS 2.3.2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at integrated developer for system Z from IBM